# Getting error * JFolder::create: Path not in open_basedir paths * Warning! Failed to move file

Tags: php, joomla

When i want to installed zip file of new component or module.i am getting below error

```
    * JFolder::create: Infinite loop detected
    * Warning! Failed to move file.
```

how can i resolved this.

Comment: I don't know anything about Joomla. But I know that that is a problem report which is completely useless. How do you expect anybody to help you if you don't give them any specific information about your problem, such as the code which is failing?

Comment: pay credit to people, give something back

Answer (score 1):

This is due to you move a joomla which is working from one server or local pc to a web server.

Follow the steps below to fix it.

1. Goto your Hosting panel >> File Manager >> Select your Domain/Sub-Domain and then open the configuration.php file.
2. Find var $log_path, it will contain the Directory path of your Old Server. Just replace the whole line with the code var $log_path = './logs';
3. Find var $tmp_path, it will also have the Directory path of your Old Server. Replace the whole line with the code var $tmp_path = './tmp';

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't need to extract the file first before installing.
Check your permissions on /tmp and /cache along with /languages and /component /modules
Give some credit back

Answer (score 0):

I came across another solution:
Comment the line of code $obd = ini_get('open_basedir');
located at...Joomla Root/libraries/joomla/filesystem/folder.php

i.e //$obd = ini_get('open_basedir');

In case it does not work you need to change your Path to Log Folder and temp folder

On you back-end, administrator....
Click System drop down menu - click global configuration

Select the System tab locate **Path to Log Folder*** and input http://yourdomain.com/logs/

Select the Server tab locate **Path to Temp Folder** and input http://yourdomain.com/tmp/

Save and try to install extensions again...

Hope it works......